# How to plot coordinate between two xticks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, plot

I want to plot some data using pgfplot. Here is a code I have written:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  legend style={legend pos = north west, font=\footnotesize, draw=none},
  legend cell align=left,
  xtick=data,
  ytick={0,5,10,...,45},
  xticklabels={0,2,4,...,16,18},
  every axis label={font=\footnotesize},
  tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
  label style={font=\footnotesize},
  enlarge x limits=false,
  enlarge y limits=false]
  \addplot[lightgray, mark=*] table [x expr = \lineno, y = Time] {Data.dat};
  \addlegendentry{x}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The content of Data.dat file is as follows:

```
 Points Time
   0        0
   2000     1.11
   4000     3.54
   6000     7.35
   8000     12.43
   10000    18.15
   12000    24.51
   14000    31.52
   16000    38.59
   17791    45.35
```

As I'm new to this site, I'm not able to post the output graph. In the output graph, the last point (17791, 45.35) is wrongly plotted at x=18 and y=45.35.
So my question is: How do I make the last point plotted correctly between points x=16 and x=18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is plotted precisely at `x=17.791`, `y=45.35`; the problem is that the label used for the last tick is wrong (you manually declared it to be 18 and this overrides the default value of `17.8`); the problem is not the plotting: the problem is the way in which you place the x labels (specifically the last one).

In the following example I show one possible way to correct the situation: I let `xtick=data` (so now the ticks and their labels are automatically picked from the table) and used `extra x ticks` and `extra xtick labels` with an auxiliary blue grid just to show where the point corresponding to 18 really is; I also changed the mark used (the mark you used is too big, in my opinion, and could produce the impression of being located at `x=18`) and also used a different color just for visualization purposes. As you can see, the x-coordinate for the last point is just where it should be (a little to the left of the red vertical line drawn for `x=18`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[
  xmax=18500,
  legend style={legend pos = north west, font=\footnotesize, draw=none},
  legend cell align=left,
  xtick=data,
   ytick={0,5,10,...,45},
   extra x ticks={18000},
   extra x tick labels={},
   extra x tick style={grid=major,tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}},
   major grid style={color=red},
   every axis label={font=\footnotesize},
   tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
  label style={font=\footnotesize},
  enlarge x limits=false,
  enlarge y limits=false,
  scaled x ticks=base 10:-3
]
  \addplot[blue, mark=x] table  {Data.dat};
  \addlegendentry{x}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use an explicit list for `xmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[
  xmax=18500,
  ymax=46,
  legend style={legend pos = north west, font=\footnotesize, draw=none},
  legend cell align=left,
   xtick={0,2000,4000,6000,8000,...,14000,16000,18000},
   ytick={0,5,10,...,45},
  major grid style={color=red},
  every axis label={font=\footnotesize},
  tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
  label style={font=\footnotesize},
  enlarge x limits=false,
  enlarge y limits=false,
  scaled x ticks=base 10:-3
]
  \addplot[blue, mark=x] table  {Data.dat};
  \addlegendentry{x}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. What shall I do if I would like to display last xticklabel as 18 and still plot the last point a little left to x=18?

Comment: @user1444462 You're welcome! I updated my answer; if you consider that my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it (by clicking the green checkmark below the vote count).